# Proofs: Relationships in Triangles

Tags: trigonometry, geometric-inequalities

**Question:** In the diagram *ABC* is a triangle in which *AB = AC* and *BC* = 1. *D* is the point on *BC* such that $\angle BAD=\theta$ and $\angle CAD=2\theta$, $BD=x$ and $CD=1-x$.

i) Use the sine rule in each of $\triangle ADB$ and $\triangle ADC$ to show that $cos \theta=\frac{1-x}{2x}$

ii) Hence show that $\frac{1}{3}\lt x \lt \frac{1}{2}$

[This is the diagram that I'm working off.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rwte.jpg)

This is for the Proofs topic of the Extension 2 HSC maths course. This belongs to a section introducing the Ineqaulity proofs.

I have successfully done part i)

> $\frac{sin\theta}{x}=\frac{sin\mu}{AD}$, $\frac{sin2\theta}{1-x}=\frac{sin\mu}{AD}$
>
> $\frac{sin\theta}{x}=\frac{sin2\theta}{1-x}$
>
> $\frac{sin\theta}{x}=\frac{2sin\theta cos\theta}{1-x}$
>
> $\frac{1-x}{2xcos\theta}=1$
>
> $\therefore cos\theta=\frac{1-x}{2x}$

But part ii) really baffles me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ii), we have $ 0< \theta < \frac \pi3\implies \frac12<\cos\theta = \frac{1-x}{2x} <1$, which leads to

$$\frac{1}{3}\lt x \lt \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Can you please further explain why $\theta$ has to be less than $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: @JieshunWang - note $\angle A =3\theta < \pi$